# EF Code First approach on relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Being new to **ASP .NET** I've been researching on entity modeling approaches and it seems `ORM` using **Entity Framework** following **Code First** is the best approach for me.

By following [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string) tutorial, I have gotten the impression that, **for each** entity, you need to create a `connectionstring` (correct me if I'm wrong) and this fact confuses me when it comes to relational data, as, per this example, the database itself seems to cover just one entity. So how is relational data handled in the EF.

**PS:** For unification purpose, please use entities `Movies`, `Customers` and the relational table named under the proper naming conventions.

Comment: Are your entities `Movies` and `Customers` belongs to different `LocalDB`?

Comment: when you say for each entity what do you mean?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan no, they are supposed to belong in the same database.

Comment: @bto.rdz I mean, the way that tutorial shows the example it makes it seem like for each model you need a connection string

Answer (score 2):

You create a connection string per `DbContext`. Here is the class that defines the DBContext:

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

To add more tables to this context, add more lines like this (for examples, `public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }`.

```
public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

Accessing these from a context:

```
public class TicketController {
    private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext ();

    public ActionResult Index(int movieId) {
       var listOfTickets = db.Tickets.Where(t=>t.MovieId == movieId).ToList();
       var parentMovie = db.Movie.Where(m=>m.Id == movieId).Single();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: since you pretty much said exactly what I would say, I added couple usage examples.  Feel free to rollback if you don't agree

Comment: so far this seems like the best answer. So basically a context could contain all tables that shares relationship: movies, customer, customermovies.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Christopher, that's correct, however a table that merely provides a many-many linking relation between two other tables (like CustomerMovies) doesn't require creation of an entity class. Instead you include a `public virtual ICollection` of Customers in the Movie class and of Movies in the Customer class. EF infers from this the need to create the CustomerMovies table behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

**[Connection String:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** Contains initialization information that is passed as a parameter from a data provider to a data source.

You need a new connection string each time you are connecting to something different (You can have two different DBContexts using the same ConnectionString), in this tutorial although the Data Source of both connection strings is the same, the AttachDbFileName is different.

When each DbContext is initialized, it will use one of those connection strings. In this tutorial, the first connection string (Default Connection) is used for membership (user accounts and such) and the other connection string is used for your MovieDBContext, and will contain Movies and other things as you progress in the tutorial.

**It's also possible to have them both in the same database.**